# Combing and sorting two querysets from different tables?

Tags: django

I have two querysets that I would like to combine and sort.

Here are my queries:

`latestbooks = Book.objects.all().order_by('-added')`
`latestvideos = Video.objects.all().order_by('-added')`

I would like to combine these queries and sort them prior to passing them to my template so that I can create a list that shows the latest activity on the site -- whether it be a new book or new video in the order they were added in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can combine and sort them as *lists* but not as querysets. Functionality, it doesn't matter much, but bear in mind that no further filtering will be possible.

```
latestbooks = Book.objects.all().order_by('-added')
latestvideos = Video.objects.all().order_by('-added')

latest = list(latestbooks) + list(latestvideos)
latest_sorted = sorted(latest, key=lambda x: x.added, reverse=True)
```

**UPDATE**

If you're working with different attribute names, it's still possible, but it starts to get ugly, and this is probably not workable for more than just two variations:

```
sorted(latest, key=lambda x: x.added if hasattr(x, 'added') else x.desadded, reverse=True)
```

Comment: Ok actually, in the second case `added` is `desadded`. Is there a way of adding two keys and combining them? Or should I rename that column to be added?